# Running new process with other user privileges from java application

Tags: java, process, privileges

i need to create new process with my application, with specific user permissions & privileges (not the user running my application).
my application is installed on unix, linux, windows (xp, vista, 7, 2000+ server).

i am starting with windows.
Runtime.exec() with "runas" command will not work, because password is required, and there is no way to embed password in runas command (there is a VB script that doing that, but its not for win7, xp).

is there a way to do that? is there an open source that handle this issue for all Operating systems?
can you give a piece of code for example?

thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a new process with another User Account on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362198/how-can-i-create-a-new-process-with-another-user-account-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Windows, but on modern Unixes the canonical way to run a command as another user is [`sudo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo).