# Equivalent of pwd.h lib of c++ in java

Tags: java, c++, unix, pwd

I have found a [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pwd.h.html) that illustrates the use of getting pwd based in the uid of the user.

I have a similar requirement in java for running a script as a different user which needs this implemetation.

The code snippet in c++ is as below:

```
static void su(const char* user)
{
    struct passwd* pwentry=getpwnam(user);
    if(!pwentry)
        COUT<<"su:getpwnam:couldnot get pwd entry for user %s",user;
    uid_t new_uid=pwentry->pw_uid;
    struct passwd* pwentry_nmsadm=getpwnam("nmsadm");
    if(!pwentry_nmsadm)
        cout<<"su:getpwnam:could not get pwd for nmsadm");
    gid_t new_gid=pwentry->pw_gid;
    if(chdir(pwentry->pw_dir)<0)
        cout<<"su:chdir";
    uid_t current_uid=geteuid();
    gid_t current_gid=getegid();
    if(current_gid!=new_gid)
    {
        if(setgid(new_gid)<0)
        cout<<"su:setgid";
    }
    if(current_uid!=new_uid)
    {
        if(setuid(new_uid)<0)
        cout<<"su: setuid";
    }
```

Please suggest some links that can be helpful(libraries that can be used) or solution to the above requirement in java.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not provide this out-of-the-box, since it is both system dependant and would break security concepts of Java.

Some possible solutions could be:

- Use a JNI wrapper to call your C++ method, so that you can do everything you need in C++
- Use `ssh` to launch the script as a different user
- Use `sudo` to launch the script as a different user

See also

- [Running UNIX commands as different user, from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012792/running-unix-commands-as-different-user-from-java)
- [How can I create a new process with another User Account on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362198/how-can-i-create-a-new-process-with-another-user-account-on-windows) (Windows specific, but one answer mentions the JNI approach)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance but I cannot use ssh or sudo as i can not pass the pwd into them in order to execute the required operations